# Remove quotation chars from file while bulk inserting data to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulk-load

This is `Users` table

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Surname NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Email NVARCHAR(30), 
    Facebook NVARCHAR(30),

    CHECK(Email IS NOT NULL OR Facebook IS NOT NULL)
);
```

This is `BULK INSERT`

```
BULK INSERT Users
FROM 'C:\Users\SAMIR\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\users.txt'
WITH (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      --FIRSTROW = 0,
      --UTF-8
      CODEPAGE = '65001'
);
```

So this is `Users.txt` file data:

```
`1, N'Alex', N'Mituchin', N'qwe@gmail.com', NULL`
```

When I load data from the file it sets `Username` to values like `N'Alex'`. But I want to have the data simply like `Alex`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How do you load the data?

Comment: Oh. I have to add bulk insert example.

Comment: Please show the script/method you are using to load `Users.txt` into your database

Comment: Look again please. I edited my question

Comment: try adding `DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'` to the `WITH` part of the query. This tells BULK INSERT to use Unicode character format when bulk importing data. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-unicode-character-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#considerations

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the nvarchar data type?

Comment: @SezMe I dont think reason is nvarchar. What is your suggestion for datatype ?

Comment: Ehhhh this might be possible with dynamic SQL? I doubt you can do bulk insert.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend loading data into a staging table where are values are strings.

Then you can use a simply query to get the final results.  In this case, you can do:

```
select (case when name like 'N''%'''
             then substring(name, 2, len(name) - 3)
             else name
        end) as name
from staging
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there no way for cut quotation char while load data from file. In this case i have to write trigger (when data included to table set data with update code block). I want to know how can i cut data while load data to table.

Comment: @SamirHemzeyev . . . There probably is.  I think this is the simplest and most general solution for getting data into a database.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better option for this. If the string delimiters and unicode indicators are consistent (they're present on all rows), you should use a format file where you can indicate delimites for each column. This will allow you to set `, N'` as delimiter between the first and second columns, `', N'` as delimiter for the second and third columns, and so on.